# Isn't same-origin policy useless with JSONP?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp, browser-security

I am starting to develop using JSONP to allow my code to be embedded into the site of another company and call my server without being blocked by the same-origin policy.

My question is simply : with this technique, anyone that could inject javascript could easily use JSONP in `<script>` tags to load content from anywhere he wants so what is the point of same-origin policy if there is this easy workaround?

I understand that the server has to reply with JSONP compatible content but it seems to me that it stays pretty easy to do whatever he wants.

Comment: Isn't mixed content blocking primarily related to https? Don't see how JSONP has anything to do with that in particular.

Comment: Ooops I used the wrong words, I mean cross-domain requests. Will edit.

Comment: JSONP is nothing else but including a `<script>` element. So I guess your question is: Why is there a same-origin policy if it can be circumvented by loading code via `<script>` elements?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I knew that JSONP is only about including a script element but as I understand it it makes the same-origin policy completely useless. Thanks for helping me, noob here.

Comment: Maybe this is a start: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8264

Comment: "I understand that the server has to reply with JSONP compatible content" — Yes, they do… and the whole point of serving JSONP is to circumvent the same origin policy… so what's the problem?

Comment: Why is this worth a downvote? Bergi answered accuratly my question showing that the SOP is not useless because of JSONP.

Comment: @Quentin the problem is : I thought the same origin policy was there to prevent javascript injections calling an external server, so for me with this workaround it was useless. Bergi shows the real point of the SOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the server has to reply with JSONP compatible content but it seems to me that it stays pretty easy to do whatever he wants.

No, that's the caveat. The information that is not publicly available is not (or at least should not be) offered as JSONP. Only content that is *supposed* to be loaded into arbitrary sites (and allow to ignore the SOP) will be offered as JSONP by its owner.

The purpose of the [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is not to protect against people who are able to inject javascript into arbitrary sites, but to protect arbitrary sites from being embedded into a possibly hostile one.

Comment: That is enlightening, I did not see it the other way around. I was halfway through in my reasoning. But is this really the only useful point of the same-origin policy? It sounds like it is.

Comment: Yes. SOP is the "default security": No page (controlled by whomever) is allowed to read content from any other pages *through the user's browser* - from his POV and possibly with his credentials. All inter-domain communication (be it JSONP, `postMessage`, CORS, etc) needs to make an explicit exception (by formatting as an executable script, by checking `event.origin`, by setting HTTP headers respectively).